# ¿Còmo optimizar tiempo de ejecución de un script?

Tags: python-3.x, lista, optimización

Buenos días cordial saludo, espero se encuentren bien la siguiente es para consultarles si conocen alguna forma de mejorar este script en cuestión de tiempo de procesamiento, ya que se me tarda hasta media hora en procesar la información, he descubierto que quien me rentaliza el proceso es la función all() entonces quería consultarles si existe otra forma a nivel computacional de mejorar dicho rendimiento del script, esas condiciones de all() me permiten filtrar una serie de listas que tienen condiciones particulares (si es toda negativa o toda positiva o si tiene cambios de signo) agradezco enormemente su colaboración.

```
for j in range(0,len(zmeshmesh)):
    Bmeshaux=[]
    Bmeshauxred=[]
    Bmeshauxholg=[]
    for r in range(len(zmeshmesh[j])):
        zmeshiter=[]
        zmeshiterred=[]
        zmeshiterholg=[]
        for m in range(len(zd[j])):
            zmeshiter.append(zmeshmesh[j][r]-zd[j][m]) #normalizando vector de cada estación con los 3 mètodos
            zmeshiterred.append(zmeshmeshred[j][r]-zd[j][m])
            zmeshiterholg.append(zmeshmeshholg[j][r]-zd[j][m])
            for i in range(0,len(zmeshiter),1): #ciclo para identificar cambio de signo en normalizada
                if (all(x > 0 for x in zmeshiter)) or (all(x < 0 for x in zmeshiter)):
                    yi,yf=0,0
                if (zmeshiter[i]>=0 and zmeshiter[i-1]<0):
                    start=i
                    try:
                        yi=round((zmeshmesh[j][r]-zd[j][start])*((yd[j][start-1]-yd[j][start])/(zd[j][start-1]-zd[j][start]))+yd[j][start],2)
                    except:
                        yi=round((zmeshmesh[j][r]-zd[j][start])*((yd[j][start-2]-yd[j][start])/(zd[j][start-2]-zd[j][start]))+yd[j][start],2)
                    if (all(s>0 for s in zmeshiter[start::])):
                        yi=0
                if (zmeshiter[i]<=0 and zmeshiter[i-1]>0):
                    end=i
                    try:
                        yf=round((zmeshmesh[j][r]-zd[j][end])*((yd[j][end-1]-yd[j][end])/(zd[j][end-1]-zd[j][end]))+yd[j][end],2)
                    except:
                        yf=round((zmeshmesh[j][r]-zd[j][end])*((yd[j][end-2]-yd[j][end])/(zd[j][end-2]-zd[j][end]))+yd[j][end],2)
                    if all((s>0 for s in zmeshiter[0:end])):
                        yf=0
```

Comment: Sin entender del todo bien qué hace el código, veo que tienes listas dentro de listas, y muchos bucles. Parece que todo esto pueda ser implementado usando `numpy` y sus arrays bidimensionales. La conversión no será trivial, pero merecerá la pena, pues `numpy` ofrece muchas operaciones "vectoriales" que operan sobre filas o columnas enteras del array "de una vez" (en realidad, internamente numpy iterará sobre los datos, pero estas iteraciones están escritas en C y compiladas a código máquina dentro de numpy por lo que son mucho más rápidas que hacerlas en python)

Comment: Además, si tu array se puede "trocear" y cada trozo ser procesado de forma independiente, puedes plantearte usar varios hilos que operen en paralelo sobre cada trozo del array. Con 4 hilos, el tiempo se reducirá a la cuarta parte (suponiendo que tu CPU tenga 4 cores). La programación multihilo con python puro en general no ayuda el tiempo, en problemas computacionales, por culpa del GIL (un lock que impide a dos hilos python ejecutar operaciones a la vez), pero usando numpy el GIL no interfiere por estar numpy hecho en C como dije.

Comment: Hola Abulafia así es, es una lista entrelistas, existe una forma de almacenar eso así en numpy, es que he usado muy poco esa librería y suelo trabajar con las que trae python.

Comment: Numpy es una librería para manejar arrays multidimensionales. Son un caso particular de listas dentro de listas, en las que todos los elementos son del mismo tipo (normalmente numérico). Pensado para cálculos matriciales, estadísticos, etc. Piensa en ella como una especie de "matlab para python". Muy eficiente y muy utilizada en el mundo del cálculo numérico. No sé si te encaja con lo que intentas hacer.